# Jfrog Pipeline - Does cronTrigger resource supports triggering a pipeline with predefined variables?

Tags: jfrog-pipelines

```
resources:
  - name: nightly_cron_trigger
    type: CronTrigger
    configuration:
      interval: "30 03 * * *" # Every day at 03:30AM UTC
      branches:
        include: *serviceBranchRegexp

pipelines:
  - name: commons_nightly
    steps:
      - name: prepare_nightly_run
        type: Bash
        configuration:
          nodePool: ci_c5large
          inputResources:
            - name: nightly_cron_trigger
            - name: commons_bitbucket
              trigger: false
          outputResources:
            - name: commons_property_bag
          environmentVariables:
            GIT_REPO_PATH:
              default: *serviceGitRepoPath

        execution:
          onStart:
            - source
```

currently we have a pipeline (runs with cron each night) where each step triggers an embedded pipeline and each step does the same - only the resources and names are changing. So I thought maybe the cron can run the main pipeline a few times at night but every run will have different params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cron resource does not support this, meaning you cant trigger a pipeline with predefined variables using cronTrigger resource.
But may be you can use property bag resource. May be you can configure like this:
input cronTrigger will trigger a pipeline step and that pipelineStep will update the output propertyBag resource with different parameters.

cronTrigger -> pipelineStep -> propertyBag

which this propertyBag resource can be a input to a different pipeline now.
[image]